# Get ActionResult from another application

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, model-view-controller, actionresult

I have MVC application, with `ActionResult` Index method. This method returns a view.

Now we decided to call this method from another application and get this `ActionResult` view to convert it into the same Html page.

I'm calling method of MVC application like this:

```
baseAddress = "http://localhost:63803/";
apiAddress = "Violations/Index";
var _client = new HttpClient();
_client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress);

try
{
    var response = _client.GetAsync(apiAddress).Result  ; 
    var content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

    return content;
}
```

And I'm getting the full HTML of the page. But how can I get real `ActionResult`? Because I want to see in my new Application the same view.

Comment: Your question doesn't make a lot of sense. Can you clarify the last sentence?

Comment: Yes. MVC application - is our service. We want to get  a View (ActionResult) from GateWay web api. So, I want to get result of the ActionResult method  (actually like a type "ActionResult" in gateway service.

Comment: You can't get an object of that type over HTTP. Why would you want to do that anyway?

Comment: Because we also have another services (WebApi,Mvc, etc.) And we want to have one GateWay service to call all of them like a bridge. So, we need to separate this MNV to client and server

Comment: Once you call real ActionResult and till it comes to you it clears MVC pipeline. That means it renders the output and send that rendered output to you. Now you want this rendered thing back to actionresult? Why?? Just make current controller action Void and flush this html in response.

Comment: If your architecture is like that, then you have something very wrong indeed. If you want to pull data from another "site" then it should be an API where you get JSON (or XML) and not HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Make Dll Of Another Project and include it in your main project, at reference. and then just use it on page and while you made call give full path like, namespace.controller.action

Comment: You can Search How to consume web api:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client